# Unable to start debugging with local IIS in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I just wasted about an hour trying to start debugging my ASP.NET project written with VS 2010 on one of my dev machines. I need to debug it with the local IIS Server but I keep getting this:

[image]

And just to show how freaking dumb Microsoft is, here's what I get if I click Help:

[image]

The most annoying part is that the exact same project runs OK on another dev machine.

So, here's what I did on this machine where it doesn't work:

1. Rebooted computer.
2. I disabled Windows firewall (completely):

[image]

3. And killed that green whatever-the-hell-its-called antivirus program from Microsoft:
   [image]
4. I made sure that IIS is installed & app pool is started in IIS manager:

[image]

So what am I missing?

PS. This is so frustrating to waste time on this stupid mislabeled error!!!

Comment: if you change the settings to use visual studio development server instead of IIS does it work in debug mode?

Comment: ok, so back to IIS, are you 100% sure you have created the virtual directory or web site configured to be used with IIS? which application pool have you configured to be used by such web application? if does not run in debug, does it run in normal runtime with no debugger? try to enable windows authentication for that web application.

Comment: a) try to launch this page in browser to see if it works or not b) try to attach to process (w3wp.exe) and see if this will work.

Comment: One more small comment, we must start Visual Studio under Administrator right on windows 7 when debug by attach to process (w3wp.exe).

Comment: I'm ready to throw in a towel. For some reason w3wp.exe doesn't even start when I try to debug it. Do I need to set up this web app through the IIS manager like I would do on a real IIS? On the other machine I ran it through VS 2010 debugger and it said that it'd do so automatically and everything loaded up just fine. Also, if I run it without debugging, then the IE loads up and shows `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage`...

Comment: @ToanVo: Forgot to say, I do run VS 2010 as admin. I also tried to change permission on the folder where this web app is located, but I can't find an account that it runs under. On the other machine w3wp runs under `DefaultAppPool` but I can't find such user account to give it any permissions. Agrhh, this is so frustrating!